# how to specify background text rectangle color in CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to specify background color for HTML using CSS.  If my `foobar.css` file is

```
back {
  background-color: #808080;
}
```

and my `index.html` is

```
<link href="foobar.css">

<p><back>foo</back></p>
<p><back>foobar</back></p>
```

then this does not work perfectly:  yes the lines have background, but the background only covers the line length, so it is jagged on the right side, and the background does not cover the space between the lines.

How to do it so that the background covers the whole rectangle around the paragraphs?

I tried `foobar.css` like

```
table {
  background-color: #808080;
}
```

and then reference that in `index.html` like

```
<table>
<p>foo</p>
<p>foobar</p>
</table>
```

but this is completely ignored.

Comment: try using `!important`

Comment: try enclosing your paragraphs in a div and then give background color to that div. This is give a rectangular colored area as you want

Comment: @Kartikeya still ignored

Comment: @MarkGaleck..plz make a fiddle for your problem...

Comment: You cannot directly use paragraphs inside a html table, it will always be rendered outside the table on the webpage. If using table is required the use tr>td>p to make it work

Comment: @AakashJain tha almost works perfectly!  Except, the background extends all the way to the window border.  I just want the background to cover the width of the widest line displayed.  I just want the smallest rectangle around the paragraphs, not the wide rectangle.

Comment: @Kartikeya can you clarify what you mean?

Comment: `<back>` is not HTML. Not all browsers let you even style such made-up elements. It is an unnecessary complication here.

Comment: The question title says “table color”, but the question body does not even use a valid HTML table and seems to have completely different real questions: about making background 100% wide and a about making backgrounds of adjacent elements join. Using a table, now suggested in answers, is a pointless complication. You should describe the actual problem and either use valid HTML or explicitly tell that you are using “custom tags” and explain how you expect browsers to handle them.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela OK I say, "text rectangle" in the title, sounds worse than "table" but at least, it does not confuse with the meaning of "table" inside HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this solves your isuue

```
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
               <p>foo</p>
               <p>foobar</p>
            </td>
       </tr>
    </table>
  <style>
      table{background-color:red;}
  </style>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because the `<table>` you write has wrong tags inside. The `<table>` tag should be composed by N `<tr>` (rows) and a `<tr>` could contains N `<td>` (cells).

This is the code that you should use.

```
<table>
  <tr>
   <td>foo</td>
  </tr>
  <tr> 
   <td>foobar</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Here is a full description of the `<table>` element and its possible content: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table

Answer (score 1):

Looks fine to me so long as you use the correct elements in your table.

HTML

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>foo</td>
        <td>bar</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
table {
  background-color: #808080;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bruj9q3r/)

**Update**

Question from original poster: "OK but... if I do this, not just this table, but all tables in my HTML will have black background. How to do it so only this one does?"

In that case, you want to add an ID to your table, and then create a CSS rule that matches that ID.

HTML

```
<table id="my-table">
    <tr>
        <td>foo</td>
        <td>bar</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>foo</td>
        <td>bar</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
#my-table {
  background-color: #808080;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ywtj57f0/)

Comment: OK but... if I do this, not just this table, but _all_ tables in my HTML will have black background.  How to do it so only this one does?

Answer (score 0):

When you use an undefined tag like `<back>`, browsers will treat it as opening an undefined element, which has *inline* rendering (`display: inline` in CSS) by default. This means that any background set on it will cover only the width of the text. Moreover, these elements are inside `p` elements, and `p` elements have top and bottom margin by default, and the backgrounds of inner element do not extend to that margin area.

To specify a background for a rectangle that occupies the available width, use the `div` element as a wrapper:

```css
.foo { background-color: #808080; }
```

```html
<div class="foo">
<p><back>foo</back></p>
<p><back>foobar</back></p>
</div>
```

There is no need for a table here. You would need a table only if we lived in the mid-1990s, when the only way to set a background color on a block was to use a single-cell table and the `bgcolor` attribute.